# Issue in Converting the Users Results from Microsoft Graph API V1.0 to Json

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using below code to get all users and then converting it to Json Data:

```
var usersForDep = await graphServiceClient1.Users.Request().Select(e => new
                        {
                            e.Department,
                            e.BusinessPhones,
                            e.MobilePhone
                        }).GetAsync();


     JObject json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(usersForDep.ToString());
```

usersForDep  is of Microsoft.Graph.Users type which has several fields like Job Title, Email, Contact. 
Please Help.

Pelase help me in converting usersForDep   to json data.

Answer (score 0):

When you "deserialize" and object, you are converting a JSON string into an object. To convert an object into a JSON string, you to "serialize" that object.

Beyond that, `usersForDep` is not a JSON response. It is already a C# object ([`GraphServiceUsersCollectionPage`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/3f594675b03a1144c9c065428cc79f24c81573e1/src/Microsoft.Graph/Requests/Generated/GraphServiceUsersCollectionPage.cs)). The SDK handles serialization and deserialization automatically.

One important note, `usersForDep.ToString()` won't serialize an object into JSON. It will simply return the string representation of an object; which in this case would be `usersForDep`'s Type.